# Should there be a separate tag for partially ordered sets?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Users who are on this site some time might have noticed that a separate tag for posets has been created and removed a few times in the past.<sup>1</sup>

Certainly, partial orders are quite an important topic. On the other hand, there already is the tag [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) which is suitable for questions about partial orders.<sup>2</sup> So by creating one additional tag we would not gain too much and we would use already two of the five possible slots for tags on such questions - since they would be typically tagged by this specific tag and also by (order-theory).

So my main questions are:

1. Should there be a separate tag for partial orders? Would such tag be actually useful?
2. If the consensus is that we do not want a separate tag for this purpose, would creating synonyms [posets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posets) $\to$ [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory), [partial-orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-orders) $\to$ [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory), etc., be useful?

The intention of the synonyms suggested in the second point is that new users might be unaware that [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) is the tag suitable for questions about partial orders, so they might be looking for a tag with "poset" or "partial order" in the name. (As witnessed by repeated creation of such tags in the past.)<sup>3</sup>

If we compare the situation with MathOverflow, they have separate tags [posets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/posets) (198 questions) and [order-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/order-theory) (378 questions). If we look at those tags, there are 87 questions [which have both tags](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/order-theory+posets) and it seems that there is a fair share of questions which are [about partial orders but do not have (posets) tag](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=%5Border-theory%5D+poset+-%5Bposets%5D+is%3Aq). So I am not sure whether separation into two tags contributes to having the site better organized on that site. This was discussed briefly also on Mathoverflow Meta, although the discussion there seems to be inconclusive: [Two tags for partially ordered sets](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/818).<sup>4</sup> (And, needless to say, the two sites are not exactly the same - so not everything that works there would also work here and vice versa.)

I would suggest to keep this discussion specifically about *partial* orders. I do not know about attempts to create a tags for linear orders (total orders) in the past - but if the need arises we can start a separate discussion about such tag. There already exists a [separate discussion about well-orderings](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17073/what-about-a-separate-tag-for-well-ordered-sets-or-should-it-be-synonym-of-ord) - and moreover well-orders seem to me sufficiently different from partial orders, so it's probably better not to discuss them in the same topic.

---

<sup>1</sup>For example, the tag [posets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posets) was created recently [in December 2017](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41781170#41781170) - including [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2568930/revisions) and [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2568929/revisions).
Shortly [after removal by a moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42185252#42185252), the tag [reappeared in January 2018](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2018/1/10) - including a new [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/937167) and [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/937166). Using the query [from this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25038/can-you-tell-who-created-a-tag/25041#25041) you can find several past occurrences of [posets](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/542457/first-10-uses-of-a-tag?tagName=posets), [poset](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/542457/first-10-uses-of-a-tag?tagName=poset) and [partial order](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/542457/first-10-uses-of-a-tag?tagName=partial-order). For example, the tag [poset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poset) was created and removed in [2013](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/511008/revisions), [2014](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1048521/revisions), [2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1369584/revisions) and [2018](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2097630/revisions).

<sup>2</sup>The [current revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/54143/revisions) of the tag-excerpt says: "Order theory deals with properties of orders, usually partial orders or quasi orders but not only those. Questions about properties of orders, general or particular, may fit into this category, as well as questions about properties of subsets and elements of an ordered set."

<sup>3</sup>To some extent in the spirit of this older discussion: [Tags as redirects for correct tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18998). (Although the idea suggested there seems to be abandoned.)

<sup>4</sup>Looking at that discussion reminded me that there is a possibility that some users might mistakenly use this for order of a group. (Typically if a user does not read the tag-excerpt and decides only based on the name of the tag.) If you look at the 75 questions tagged [order-theory+group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory+group-theory), many of them are mistagged. However, this is only tangentially related to this discussion.

Comment: I do think a synonym [tag:posets] $\to$ [tag:order-theory] (among others) would help users tag questions in this instance. As an aside, “order theory” sounds kind of fancy. What I mean is that I’ve used posets fairly frequently, but I don’t think I’ve ever proven anything about posets the same way I’ve proven things about groups, for example. So, a [tag:posets] tag feels like a better fit *for how I use posets* than [tag:order-theory], in my mind. However, this opens a “tool vs. central object of study” distinction that’s not present for other tags, as far as I know...

Comment: @pjs36 I am not sure whether these are exactly examples similar to what you are asking about but ([tag:rings]) and ([tag:ring-morphisms]) are [synonyms of ring-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/ring-theory/synonyms) and 
([tag:algebraic-closure]) is a [synonym of field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/field-theory/synonyms).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that we should take a lot from the tagging system on MathOverflow. It has some merits (e.g. the top-level arXiv tags, but even those are eroding), but for more specific topics it's more haphazard, and as the site is significantly smaller and less active, this is not a terrible problem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I am aware that MO and Math.SE are different in many aspects, including some things related to tagging. (I have included this also in the question.) Still it is at least some kind of data point - when somebody considers whether or not this tag could be useful, checking how the same tag is doing on MO cannot hurt.

Comment: When tags become too narrow, there is not enough new posts to make worth while to bother reading it.  Order theory tag needs to be improved to weed out algebra - order of an element in a group stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess since I've been the only one to weigh in, I'll do so "formally" in an answer.

- I think creating synonyms [posets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posets) $\to$ [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) and [partial-orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-orders) $\to$ [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) will help users tag questions related to orders.

Synonyms are pretty cheap to create, and don't have the same downsides as creating too many tags, right? I personally didn't really know "order theory" was a subject in its own right, before seeing the tag here (and thus wouldn't have searched for it / tried to apply the tag to any questions I may have had about partial orders).

- I personally think synonyms are enough, and that we don't need a separate tag for partially ordered sets.

I suspect (but have no evidence to support my suspicion) that a significant portion, if not a clear majority, of questions tagged with [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) deal with partial orders, and not something less stringent like a preorder (although the more specialized topic of [lattice-orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lattice-orders) has been relatively popular, with 821 questions using the tag at the time of writing). Thus, I suspect that splitting off questions about partial orders would leave the tag [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) significantly less used, and it's not terribly popular to begin with.

My personal feelings are that the topic is not as popular as e.g. [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory) where significant tag specialization is necessary, nor does there seem to be a need to split questions about "genuine" order theory from those of a more elementary nature (as with the splits in our [set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory) or [number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) tags and their elementary versions). But, I would especially welcome dissenting opinions here.

- I think [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) should stay the master tag.

While there is potential for misusing [order-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/order-theory) for, e.g., the concept of "order" in group theory, a more specialized tag like [partial-orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-orders) isn't a good fit for all questions pertaining to more general types of orders. I do think the current name is most appropriate for the master tag.

Comment: It is infelicitous that "order" is a term with varied meanings (besides group theory, polynomial degrees, matrix ranks, and derivative hierarchies come to mind).  Still, and noting that similar potential for misuse exists in other tags, I'm happy with picking "order theory" as the master synonym.

Comment: I created those syns but massively disagree with "and don't have the same downsides as creating too many tags, right?" as a general statement. Some synonyms are toxic, way more than any tag ever could be. The worst is it's a silent poison. Questions end up with non-sense tags and the poster might not even realize.